# Migradoc dynamic page size

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using Migradoc to generate PDF documents in my application.

Now I need to generate a single page document with fixed width and **dynamically calculated height** based on the content height.

```
var document = new Document();
var section = doc.AddSection();
section.PageSetup.PageWidth = "100mm";
// section.PageSetup.PageHeight = ???
var p1 = section.AddParagraph();
// ...
var p2 = section.AddParagraph();
// ...
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I would do: I would set the page height to a very huge value and then I'd render the document. Once it has been rendered you can access all the position and dimension information (this may require adding a new method as described in this thread: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1904#p1904).

Probably I'd add an empty dummy paragraph at the end and use the Y position of this dummy paragraph to determine the required height.

Render the document again with the new page size or open the PDF file with PDFsharp and set the MediaBox to the size new need.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had to create documents for a slip printer (tax invoice, shift report etc.) with dynamic page heights.

[Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/?source=directory) (at the bottom of the page) the /pdfsharp/PDFsharp 1.50 (beta 3)/PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta3b.zip source code (at the time of this writing), build it and add the dll's to your project.

Set a ridiculously large height at the beginning for your PageHeight

```
Document document = new Document();

Section section = document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup.PageWidth = Unit.FromMillimeter(100);
section.PageSetup.PageHeight = Unit.FromMillimeter(10000);

//add tables etc.
//note: all my tables are added using document.LastSection.Add(table)

DocumentRenderer renderer = new DocumentRenderer(document);
renderer.PrepareDocument();

RenderInfo[] info = renderer.GetRenderInfoFromPage(1);
int index = info.Length - 1;

double stop = info[index].LayoutInfo.ContentArea.Y.Millimeter + info[index].LayoutInfo.ContentArea.Height.Millimeter; //add more if you have bottom page margin, borders on the last table etc.
section.PageSetup.PageHeight = Unit.FromMillimeter(stop);
```

This might not work 100% exactly for your scenario but you will be able to get the coordinates and size of the last table added and work out your page height from there.

Thanks to ThomasH for the info and the link, it helped me to figure this out.